# Finding records that occur most commonly together in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of ingredients:

```
ing_id, ing_name
1      , ing1
...
```

a table of recipes:

```
rec_id, rec_name
1     , rec1
...
```

and a table showing the connection between the two:

```
id, ing_id, rec_id
1,  1, 1
2,  1, 2
3,  2, 1
4,  3, 3
...
```

How can I find the ingredients that most commonly appear in the same recipe?

Comment: What do you mean by most commonly? Are you thinking of listing combination of ingredients and their count by recipe? If a recipe has 3 ingredients, that'd be counting ing1+2, ing1+3, ing2+3. If a recipe has 4 ingredients, that'd be counting ing1+2, ing1+3, ing1+4, ing2+3, ing 2+4, ing3+4, ing1+2+3, ing1+2+4, ing1+3+4 etc. and then sorting by highest count first. Is that what you want?

Comment: Updated the example to better illustrate the problem: In the example above, ingredients 1 and 2 have one common recipe (rec_id = 1), while ingredients 1 and 3 have zero common recipe. The same for ingredients 2 and 3. So we would want the output to be 1 and 2, as that is the combination with most common recipes (one > zero).

Comment: Let's say, you had 5 different recipes. `Recipe1` had ingredients i1, i2 and i3. `Recipe2` had i1, i2, i3, i4, i5. `Recipe3` had i3, i4, i7, i8. `Recipe4` had i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i9, i10. `Recipe5` had all i1..i10 ingredients. What would your output look like?

Comment: 3 and 4. They both appear together in four recipes (2,3,4,5), which is higher than any other pair of ingredients.

Comment: You are better off doing this math outside of SQL in a programming language of your choice. In this above example, if i2 was in the same recipes as i3, you'd want to produce an output of i2, i3 and i4. That means, you are looking to see which 2+ combination of ingredients appear most across all recipes.

Comment: I agree that it is easier in a programming language. But in any case, if i2 was in the same recipe as i3, the expected result would be (2, 3), (2, 4) and (3, 4).

Comment: Ah, I see...you are looking for ingredients in pairs! If I get some time tonight, I'll try writing a stored proc in MySQL that - I feel - might get you the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a self join and `group by`:

```
select c1.ing_id, c2.ing_id, count(*)
from connections c1 join
     connections c2
     on c1.rec_id = c2.rec_id and c1.ing_id < c2.ing_id
group by c1.ing_id, c2.ing_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

If you actually want the names instead of the ids, you'll need two more joins to bring them in.

Comment: This is so much simpler than I was thinking!