# How can I find out the most common combination of a column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of Client and Product(that the client purchased)

| Client | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | A |
| Alex | B |
| Alex | C |
| Alex | D |
| Peter | A |
| Peter | B |
| Peter | C |
| Aline | C |
| Aline | D |
| Aline | E |
| Aline | F |
| Aline | G |
| Joao | B |
| Joao | C |
| Joao | D |
| Joao | E |
| Nikky | A |
| Nikky | B |
| Nikky | C |

I want to know the most common combination of 3 products that the client purchased, like this table, the final result will be "A,B,C"
Since it happened 3 times (Alex, Peter, Nikky)

Comment: So you have table like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/L9n-qu6m), and what did you try to get your problem sovled?

Comment: Maybe, when you did research, you could have found: [mysql - find most popular two column value combination and sort by popularity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912237/mysql-find-most-popular-two-column-value-combination-and-sort-by-popularity), then this solution is pretty close!  (or: [Find the most popular combinations SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66493487/find-the-most-popular-combinations-sql), or [Finding records that occur most commonly together in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55697476/finding-records-that-occur-most-commonly-together-in-sql) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a *"finished"* version of Selaka's answer.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', cp1.Product, cp2.Product, cp3.Product) AS ProductCombo, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM Client_Product cp1
JOIN Client_Product cp2 ON cp1.Client = cp2.Client AND cp1.Product < cp2.Product
JOIN Client_Product cp3 ON cp2.Client = cp3.Client AND cp2.Product < cp3.Product
GROUP BY ProductCombo
ORDER BY Cnt DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WdlzngJj).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sample data you provided is from the `Client_Product` table. Here's how you can achieve this.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', t.Product1, t.Product2, t.Product3) AS ProductCombination, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM (
    SELECT t1.Client, t1.Product AS Product1, t2.Product AS Product2, t3.Product AS Product3
    FROM Client_Product t1
    JOIN Client_Product1 t2 ON t1.Client = t2.Client AND t1.Product < t2.Product
    JOIN Client_Product2 t3 ON t2.Client = t3.Client AND t2.Product < t3.Product
) t
GROUP BY ProductCombination
ORDER BY Count DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

PS: feel free to rename the table name according by replacing `Client_Product` if it is different from your table name.

Comment: Why do you introduce two tables (`Client_Product` and `your_table`) while there is only 1 in the question ? (and AFAICS the definition is not the same as in the question)

Comment: Can you explian what is the different between Client_Product and your_table？ And what is t2, t3？